# Facet API and views contextual filters (facets block on non-search page)

Tags: 7, views, search

I'm using Facets API with SOLR and it all works fine.

I also have a standard view set up using a facets block from the search-index view. This also works OK, but it shows the complete unfiltered facet list.

What I'd like to do is apply a contextual filter from the path to the facet block, but it doesn't seem to work - I get nothing.

I'm wondering whether this is possible and if so how (and if anyone even understands what I'm asking?!)

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, worked this out myself:

Use the contextual filters prefixed "Search:" in the list (not "Indexed node:". There are 2:
"Search: Fulltext search" and "Search: Indexed taxonomy term fields"

Not sure if Search: Fulltext search is ideal as I'm using it for place names and there are a few with more than one word.